# BigQuery: extract SECOND from TIMESTAMP

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can i run this query?

**Error Message**: No matching signature for function EXTRACT for argument types: DATE_TIME_PART FROM INT64. Supported signatures: EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATE); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIMESTAMP [AT TIME ZONE STRING]); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM DATETIME); EXTRACT(DATE_TIME_PART FROM TIME) at [12:12]

They both give the same error message

```
 WHERE EXTRACT( SECOND FROM event_timestamp )
             - EXTRACT( SECOND FROM last_event) >= (60 * 10)
        OR last_event IS NULL
```

```
 WHERE EXTRACT( SECOND FROM event_timestamp AT TIME ZONE "UTC")
             - EXTRACT( SECOND FROM last_event  AT TIME ZONE "UTC") >= (60 * 10)
        OR last_event IS NULL
```

[image: example timestamp]

Comment: Is the event timestamp storing [unix epoch timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) in microseconds?

Comment: Please explain the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `TIMESTAMP_MICROS()`

```
WHERE EXTRACT( SECOND FROM TIMESTAMP_MICROS(event_timestamp))
             - EXTRACT( SECOND FROM last_event) >= (60 * 10)
        OR last_event IS NULL
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want events that are more than 10 minutes from the previous timestamp, just use some arithmetic and comparisons:

```
where event_timestamp > last_event + (60 * 10 * 1000000) or
      last_event is null
```

You are storing the timestamp as a microseconds value.  You don't need to convert to another type.

If you really wanted to convert this to `timestamp` values, you could use:

```
where timestamp_micros(event_timestamp) > timestamp_add(timestamp_micros(last_event), interval 10 minute) or
      last_event is null
```

In particular, you don't want to extract seconds.  That value is always going to be between 0 and 59.